# Find inside callback of another find (...), how to escape from callback hell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, mongoose, mean

(First: I'm sorry, I don't speak english very well!)

I wanna return the results of 3 finds in one array.
My code (next) is running well, but I'm in callback hell!

```
_Schema
  .static('retrieveAll', function(cb) {
    query = {};
    this.find(query, function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        cb(err, null);
        return;
      }

      if(data)
        all = data;
      else
        all = [];

      _StoresModel.find(query).select('contact address').exec(function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
          cb(err, null);
          return;
        }

        if(data) {
          all = data.reduce(function(coll, item) {
            coll.push(item);
            return coll;
          }, all);
        }

        _CustomersModel.find(query).select('contact address').exec(function(err, data) {
          if(err) {
            cb(err, null);
            return;
          }

          if(data) {
            all = data.reduce(function(coll, item) {
              coll.push(item);
              return coll;
            }, all);
          }

          cb(null, all);          
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

I've a FIND inside a FIND inside a FIND.
Is there anyway to improve this?

### SOLUTION:

_Schema
  .static('retrieveAll', function(cb) {
    var model = this;

```
_async.parallel(
  { contacts: function(cb) {
      model.find({}).exec(cb);
    }
  , stores: function(cb) {
      _StoresModel.find({}).select('contact address').exec(cb);
    }
  , costumers: function(cb) {
      _CostumersModel.find({}).select('contact address').exec(cb);
    }
  }
, function(err, data) {
  if(err) {
    cb(err, null);
    return
  }

  var ret = [];
  if(data.contacts.length > 0) {
    ret = ret.concat(data.contacts);
  }
  if(data.stores.length > 0) {
    ret = ret.concat(data.stores);
  }
  if(data.costumers.length > 0) {
    ret = ret.concat(data.costumers);
  }

  cb(null, ret);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at npm [Async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async). It a great library of different patterns that can be used on node.js.

You will probably want to use the [waterfall](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#waterfalltasks-callback) if there is a Chronological priority or [parallel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#paralleltasks-callback) pattern if they can all execute in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Promises](https://www.promisejs.org/).

(untested) example:

```
var RSVP = require('rsvp');
var all = [];

_Schema.static('retrieveAll', function(cb) {
    query = {};

    findPromise(this, query)
    .then(function (data) {
        all = data;
        return findPromise(_StoresModel, query, 'contact address');
    })
    .then(function (stores) {
        all = all.concat(stores);
        return findPromise(_CustomersModel, query, 'contact address');
    })
    .then(function (customers) {
        all = all.concat(customers);
        cb(null, all);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        cb(err, null);
    });
});

function findPromise(Model, query, select) {
    return new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Model.find(query).select(select || '*').exec(function (err, data) {
            return err ? reject(err) : resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

That example is using [RSVP](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird), but there are also other promise implementations such as [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird).

And a side note, you can use `concat` to concatenate arrays instead of using `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

Some server-side promise libraries like [q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) and [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) would clean up your code substantially and eliminate the mess of callback hell.